# Which type of retention firebase presents, Rolling or Classic?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am currently working on an in-house solution which will also provide a drill down retention graphs and I am comparing my results against retention presented on firebase, for that I need to understand whether it shows Classic or Rolling retention.

I searched around and couldn't find an answer, I'm assuming that they are using classic but I am not 100% sure,   your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Retention Cohorts are based on Classic retention model.

It does not yet report cohorts based on Rolling or Range model. If you would like to have this feature, please file a ticket against Firebase Support.